# Verifying file type of ANY upload

Tags: php, security

I read that for images, it's not safe to depend on the file extension and that it's better to try to open the php with an image library like gd to verify its extension.

What about other types of files? If I have a .doc or .pdf or any other file type, how can I really tell the file type is really what it claims it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a *nix system the `file` command does a pretty good job at guessing mime type. It is not perfect, and fails on 'nested' types like `.tar.gz` but it is pretty good.

As i understand it [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) uses the same magic numbers approach as `file` without needing to go to the shell...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for any file type, but you can check mime type using [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) or [filetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php).

Comment: `filetype` tells you only if the file is a block device regular file directory etc. for all uploads it will just return "file". also mime_content_type is deprecated.

Comment: @tobyodavies. I meant fileinfo and its finfo_file. Sorry for mistake.